# Facebook Graph Api not returning all pages

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

My Facebook profile is set as admin for 3 pages. But when I call the following address on postman e see that it returns only one of the pages:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.12/me/accounts?fields=access_token,name,id,perms
```

This is the response:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "access_token": "xxx",
            "name": "Test Page",
            "id": "1234",
            "perms": [
                "ADMINISTER",
                "EDIT_PROFILE",
                "CREATE_CONTENT",
                "MODERATE_CONTENT",
                "CREATE_ADS",
                "BASIC_ADMIN"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "paging": {
        "cursors": {
            "before": "xxx",
            "after": "xxx"
        }
    }
}
```

And When I [debug the token](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/) I used to make the call everything seems OK, image below:
[image]

What Am I missing that causes it not to return the 3 pages That I'm admin of?

Comment: I am having the same problem. I suspect is something with the other pages not being in the test mode, like your own, but that is just a suspicion. I don't know how to confirm.

Comment: Please check this link. https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/347345726022992/

Comment: Please check this answer, it may help you:- [Facebook API me/accounts returns not all pages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76340626/12326605)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but I had the same issue, adding the business_management permission fixed it for me.  I think those specific pages are set as "Business" types rather than "Personal".